Foundation repair at garage wall
Above grade section of concrete is damaged where the brickwork of the house meets the garage. The house has a basement though it does not extend beneath the garage. Previous owners appear to have attempted some patching. House was built in 1965 on clay rich soil.
There is a shallow crack across the garage floor as well as a crack across the concrete driveway (about 3 feet "below" the photo).
I would at minimum like to keep water out of the cracks.
How do I approach this?


Be aware of a couple things: 1. The garage and sidewalk slabs are not foundation. They're essentially just floors. 2. The cracks don't just exist at the points you mentioned. They're also probably running down any and all of those tooled control joints. 3. The fix to the foundation wall is merely cosmetic. 4. You haven't really asked a specific question. What problem are you trying to solve?

I agree with all of your points and I'd be happy to use a new title if one were suggested. The question is "How do I approach this?" because I do not presume to fully understand the problem.

You must be asking for a reason. Is water leaking now? Are you merely seeking to make it look better?

I'd like to prevent further damage. It appears that water can enter at the base.
